# Using RAM stick with different voltage?

Tags: memory, voltage

I would like to upgrade the RAM of my laptop.

- its a Toshiba Satellite L850 - 13D, Windows 10 , 64 bits,
- it has 2 slots for RAM,
- the one I have is 4gb, I don't know if I can add another one, but with different voltage,
- I used the scan of crucial.com, and all the results are with a different voltage,

The objective was to get 8GB of RAM, and I know that I can have a better performance with 2x4GB than with 1x8GB.

Can somebody tell me if it would be bad to run a RAM with different voltage? (the voltage of the RAMs from the results of crucial.com are 1.35v)

[image]

Comment: Screenshot says 1.5, but you wrote 1.35. Am I missing something here?

Comment: i mean the one i have is 1.5v but the ones suggested at crucial.com are all 1.35v

Comment: Oh. I'm a tube light. I recommend buying a RAM with the same voltage as your PC supports now. I have read somewhere that some latest motherboards support both voltages together. But I've tried and fried a RAM, so yeah, don't mix voltages.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the intricacies of RAM, but my understanding was that for you to get better performance on 2 x 4 gig sticks over a single 8 gig stick you would need the RAM to be a matched pair - ie same make and model.  (Not saying this won't work - just speaking to the reason you gave for wanting a 4 gig module over an 8 gig module)

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop runs standard 1.5v RAM sticks, so you'll want to get that. Some places say that if you put low voltage RAM into a regular voltage slot, it will just ramp it up to 1.5v. However, the manufacture tested their RAM at 1.35v, so it has a chance to act wonky. In the opposite case, if you put 1.5v RAM in a low voltage RAM slot, it will not work because it is not giving enough power to the RAM stick.

It my mind, it's never good to mix RAM. I recommend always getting something that matches the speed and voltage of your other RAM stick(s).

Here is a [link](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/dms-memory/toshiba/satellite-l850-13d.htm) that has specifications of what RAM you should get.

As long as you get something that is PC3-12800 and not PC3**L**-12800, you will be fine.

EDIT: Also your laptop supports upto 16GB of RAM according to the link I shared. So getting another 4GB stick will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

PC RAM are built to carry some certain amount of voltages,
For example let's use capacitor to explain it.
A cap. of 450v by 120uf will receive a volt from 0 - 450 at the power of 120uf,  which means it has an internal endurance of upto 450 volts. If u pass such cap.  to a volt beyond its rating will fly it.
So your ram of 1.35v can't endure 1.5v for a long time because of its internal resistance.
So Use a ram that is compatible with your system only or buy a PC with 1.35 or 1.2v ram.